assert with formatted failure string
In pseudocode I would like to do this:
func(int a, int b) {
  assert(a == b, std::format("values differ: {}!={}", a, b));
}

or
func(int a, int b) {
  assert(a == b, [&a,&b]() { return std::format("values differ:{}!={}", a, b);});
}

because I want to printout a failure message that is more verbose.
Is there some standard way to achieve this?

If the values are different, does it really matter what their actual values are? If you need to debug, just catch the abortion in the debugger and check the values?

Test frameworks provide something like ASSER_EQ and whatever they do then doesn't matter, hide how you are doing it so this question doesn't matter

If this really is a precondition for your function. Do not assert, just throw an exception (where you can put whatever message you like in) or return an std::expected/std::optional when it happens. Because if your code continues in release build you will have issues. Also add unit tests for func and ensure it has the right behavior for all possible (including incorrect) inputs.

The above is an example. I'm interested in a general method. Maybe assert like std header doesnt supply that and I need to implement it myself. But maybe one of the new c++ standard has a solution already? I assume it is a common case. I want the runtime formatting to be inside of the assert() statment.

For messages in asserts, I use assert((a == b) && "that's not good");.  That could be used with a lambda to print out a message of your choosing, but it would be somewhat awkward / clumsy to use.  I'd make my own assert_msg(cond, msg) to print out a message string if the condition fails.

Building on Eljay if you want assert instead of exception you can say. assert (a==b || [&](){std::print(std::cerr,"values differ: {}!={}\n",a,b); return 0;}()); Yes it is clumsier than assert_msg but it puts the real assert to the place you want, not to the inside of a function.

As far as I know there is no standard way in C++ to achieve exactly what you are asking for.
cppreference.com - assert:

There is no standardized interface to add an additional message to assert errors. A portable way to include one is to use a comma operator provided it has not been overloaded, or use && with a string literal:
assert(("There are five lights", 2 + 2 == 5));
assert(2 + 2 == 5 && "There are five lights");


This obviously doesn't allow for runtime formatting.

If you really need to use runtime formatting you can either use some other assertion tools or create your own assert macro or wrapper which could look like the following:
#include <string>
#include <format>
#include <cassert>

#define TO_WIDE_STR_(str) L ## str
#define TO_WIDE_STR(str) TO_WIDE_STR_(str)
#define myAssert(expr, msg) static_cast<void>(static_cast<bool>(expr) || (myAssertImpl(TO_WIDE_STR(#expr), msg, TO_WIDE_STR(__FILE__), __LINE__), false))

[[noreturn]] void myAssertImpl(const wchar_t* exprStr, const std::wstring& msg, const wchar_t* file, unsigned line) {
    std::wstring str{ msg };
    str += L" assert(";
    str += exprStr;
    str += L")";

    _wassert(str.c_str(), file, line);
}

void func(int a, int b) {
    myAssert(a == b, std::format(L"values differ: {}!={}", a, b));
}

Note that I compiled this using msvc on Windows and, since the assert macros definition is not specified by the standard, this wrapper might not work for your environment.
You could also just ignore the native assert implementation and write it completely yourself, following the description from cppreference.com - assert.
#include <string>
#include <source_location>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define myAssert(expr, msg) static_cast<void>(static_cast<bool>(expr) || (myAssertImpl(#expr, msg), false))

[[noreturn]] void myAssertImpl(const char* exprStr, const std::string& msg, std::source_location location = std::source_location::current()) {
    std::cerr << "Assertion failed!\n"
        << "  > " << exprStr << '\n'
        << "  > " << msg << '\n'
        << "  > FILE: " << location.file_name() << '\n'
        << "  > FUNCTION: " << location.function_name() << '\n'
        << "  > LINE: " << location.line() << '\n'
        << "  > COLUMN: " << location.column() << '\n';

    std::abort();
}


maybe I have to just:
#define assert_if(expr, fmt) do { if (!(expr)) { std::string f = fmt;  printf("%s:%d:%s%s\n", __FILE__,__LINE__,#expr, f.c_str()); abort(); } } while(0);

